# How to compare in an over all manner while choosing optimal code considering function calls costs and code redundancy?

Tags: java, constructor

Which method to choose if you're a coder in some programming contest or you're developing an android app and you want it to be efficient or some other scenario? 
In the first method there are two normal unchained constructors for a and a,b.

```
public class Sample {

int a;
int b;

public Sample(){}

public Sample(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public Sample(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
}
```

In the second method the constructors are chained.

```
public class Sample {

int a;
int b;

public Sample(){}

public Sample(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public Sample(int a, int b) {
    this(a);
    this.b = b;
}
```

Comment: Only profiler can tell in your specific case, but in general there will be no difference. Comparing to memory allocation one extra call is nothing (and it most probably will be inlined anyway).

Comment: Write clear, understandable code first and don't worry about microoptimizations unless you have numbers that prove a specific part of your code is a problem.

Comment: And write code when it is needed. Perhaps some of the constructors are never used.